# R - list all global variables

Tags: r

I'd like to list all the global variables in my script. Here is what I have so far

```
MyVariables<-objects()
for (i in MyVariables) {
  print(i)
}
```

The above code works and prints out the names of all my global variables. However, I cant seem to find a way to also print out the values of the variables inside the loop. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There aren't any variables inside the loop...

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich - No, I had cut and pasted a small snippet of a larger body of code. The above snippet in itself does not have any variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `get`

```
a <- 5
b <- 10
for (obj in c("a", "b")) print(get(obj))
#[1] 5
#[1] 10
```

Comment: ugh, it seems so simple and yet I couldn't figure it out. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 10):

If you want to print all the names and values of the variables in the global environment you can just do:

```
print(as.list(.GlobalEnv))
```

That will potentially print a huge amount of info, it may be better to do:

```
str(as.list(.GlobalEnv))
```

or

```
library(TeachingDemos)
TkListView(as.list(.GlobalEnv))
```

Also look at the `ls.str()` function.

Comment: You could also do `names(as.list(.GlobalEnv))` if you just want a vector

Answer (score 1):

If you have same names of variables you could try

```
get('your_variable_name', envir=i)
```