# Is there a function that recreates the grid style environment viewer as a data frame?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a function that recreates the grid style environment viewer in RStudio as a data frame? Or is it an accessible object somewhere?

I understand that I could create something similar with a mixture of ls, class, object.size and length functions. But I was wondering if there was a base function or existing method that achieves that same thing?

[image: Grid style environment viewer]

edit: My problem is not the same as the duplicate suggested as that is regarding looping through global environment and accessing object contents. I am aware I could manually make my own function to make the data frame I would like to know if a function already exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - list all global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166208/r-list-all-global-variables)

Comment: @ottlngr My question is not the same I simply want to know if there is an easy way that creates the table in the picture as a data frame. If the answer is no that is fine I will make my own function I just wanted to check one didn't exist already.